# Return a single value from CI model method

Tags: codeigniter

I've got a method that's meant to return a single value. Because `->result()` returns an array I'm using the following to return the single value I'd like to get:

```
return array_pop($this->db->query($SQL)->result())->event_name;
```

while it works perfectly fine, I'm wondering if there's something built into CI that maybe I've missed in the documentation. I also use this same trick to return a single record:

```
return array_pop($this->db->query($SQL)->result());
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`row_array()` will return you the 1st row found as an array, and `row()` will return it as an object.

So instead of `array_pop`, you can use:

```
return $this->db->query($SQL)->row()->event_name;
```

OR

```
return $this->db->query($SQL)->row_array();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 1):

When you do what Rocket suggested, you can get a single value by just picking from that array. For example, I used this query to get count of rows:

```
function getNumberOfArticles() {
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS returnVal FROM articles")->row_array();
    return $result['returnVal'];
}
```